# openssl generates the same public key from bash script

Tags: bash, openssl, key

Im trying to generate multiple pairs of private - public keys with openssl 
Im using this bash script.

```
openssl genrsa -out /etc/dkim10.key 1024 && openssl rsa -in /etc/dkim.key -out /etc/dkim10.pub -pubout &&
openssl genrsa -out /etc/dkim11.key 1024 && openssl rsa -in /etc/dkim.key -out /etc/dkim11.pub -pubout &&
openssl genrsa -out /etc/dkim12.key 1024 && openssl rsa -in /etc/dkim.key -out /etc/dkim12.pub -pubout
```

the private keys are different but the public key is always the same. the .pub files are identical when compared with diff. the same happens if I try to generate the pairs one by one. is this normal ?  and how can I make it generate different public keys?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same private key for each public key command: `openssl rsa -in /etc/dkim.key`.

You need to use the correct private key.